# Oracle alternative edition for Windows Server 2012

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, compatibility-level

Does Oracle 11.2 support Windows Server 2012? Any alternative for Windows Server 2012 with respect to Oracle editions?

I checked in internet but their [forums](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10766492), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988156/oracle-11gr2-installation-in-windows-server-2012) says its not currently released for Windows Server editions.

Any alternative Oracle editions for Windows Server 2012 64bit?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that information the the Oracle reference document 1307195.1: *Certification Information for Oracle Database on Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)*.

The latest Windows server version where 11.2 is supported is Windows 2008R2. Oracle 12c (12.1) is supported on Windows 2012 (including Hyper-V guests), but only in single instance mode (no RAC).

You can also find that information in the install guides, e.g.:

- [11.2 install guide, software requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/reqs.htm#CHDHGGFE) - Windows 2012 not listed
- [12.1 install guide, software requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/reqs.htm#CHDHGGFE) - Four editions of Windows 2012 x64 listed (note that the Server Core edition is not supported).

Answer (score 1):

April 2014 update: 11.2.0.4 is supported on Windows Server 2012 (64-bit only)

The latest certification information for Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2) is available on My Oracle Support (formerly OracleMetaLink) at:  https://support.oracle.com